# export default in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm working through a tutorial on how to create a restful api using express and mongoose.

I'm understanding everything except for this bit right here

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import config from './config';

export default callback => {
    // connect to the database
    let db = mongoose.connect(config.mongoUrl);

    // callback db
    callback(db);
}
```

I understand what its purpose is and how to call it.
What's confusing me is the callback(db) part.

Is that a built in function or is it somehow calling itself?

Comment: `callback` is the name of the first and only parameter to the anonymous function being exported. That parameter is expected to be a function, which gets called at `callback(db);`

Comment: Ooooh, ok! That makes way more sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`callback` isn't the function's name in this case. `export default` is exporting an anonymous arrow function which takes `callback` as an argument. Since it only has one argument, they don't need to be wrapped in parens for it to be valid JavaScript. When a function is passed in, it will call it asynchronously, returning the data passed to the callback function. To illustrate, consider the following example.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import config from './config';

export default callback => {
    // connect to the database
    setTimeout( function () {
        let db = mongoose.connect(config.mongoUrl);

        callback(db);
    }, 1000); // simulate latency

}
```

And then, when you import the file elsewhere:

```
import db from './db';

db( database => {
    // One second later, this function would be called. 
    // Do something with the database here.
});
```

Hopefully this example illustrates this concept clearly.

Answer (score 2):

This is a single param arrow function, check out its description on mdn

```
// Parentheses are optional when there's only one parameter:
(singleParam) => { statements }
singleParam => { statements }
```

[MDN source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 2):

That code uses arrow function. So it's the same as this:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import config from './config';

export default function(callback) {
    // connect to the database
    let db = mongoose.connect(config.mongoUrl);

    // callback db
    callback(db);
}
```

so this function is called back by some other module using a callback function as a parameter which is the runned with `callback(db)`

Hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

`callback` is assumed to be a function definition. As you have in your example, it is invoked with `db` as its argument.

Callbacks are used primarily for asynchronous operations, where the program continues to execute even though `db` is not yet ready. This is called "[non-blocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm)" execution. That way, when the `db` data is available, it is then passed to `callback` and executed.

Hope this helps!